# Unable to access Spree Admin panel after updating the authentication, verify user email from console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, spree-auth-devise

So I'm creating a very basic Spree Rails app. I was able to access the Admin panel by just going to http://localhost:3000/admin But after setting up the authentication when I try to access the administration after entering my email and password I get that I have to verify my email. How can I verify my user email using the console?

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick,

```
user = Spree::User.find_by(email: 'spree@example.com')
user.confirm!
```

Comment: tested with spree version 3.6.4, just `user.confirm` without the exclamation mark works.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in my Spree Rails app, I think if your using Devise this will work.

```html
user = Spree::User.first
user.password='123456'
user.password_confirmation='123456'
user.email='youremail@example.com'
user.skip_confirmation!
user.save
```